# FastReport3.5 RichEdit report preview freezes when text uses a Chinese font

Tags: delphi-7, fastreport, richedit

I use FastReport3.5 in my Delphi7 program to show reports.
Sometime when I preview my report the program freezes.
When I change the RichEdit font, I can preview the report normally.
I thought the RichEdit component didn't support Chinese very well, but when I changed the font to Tahoma, the problem happened again.
This problem appeared two more times. All I could do was change the RichEdit font, but I do not think changing the font is the best method to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use latest FR 5.6.2
If problem still exists - create small demo project with problem and send it to support@fast-report.com